# Get selected value from json array with multiple values

Tags: javascript, php

Given i have a JSON file where i store my pizza to reference into my HTML with PHP and Javascript, like so:

```
"Pizza": [
{
        "id": 46,
        "name": "Rio Mare",
        "price": {
          "piccola": 18.00,
          "normale": 21.00,
          "famiglia": 41.00
        },
        "description":"Zwiebeln, Thunfisch, Kapern, Oliven und Knoblauchöl",
        "imgName": "arancini-removebg.png"
      }
]
```

and

```
<!--Loop through all the items inside the group Pizza-->
<?php foreach($items['Pizza'] as $item): ?>

<!--Display item price-->
<div class="product_price">$<?php echo $item['price'] ?></div>

<!--Selection-->
<div class="add_to_card">
  <select class="dressing_tab">
    <option disabled hidden selected value="Dressing">Grösse</option>
    <option value="piccola">piccola(24cm)</option>
    <option value="normale">normale(30cm)</option>
    <option value="famiglia">famiglia(50cm)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

if i want the price to change if a selection is made i would go like so
`<?php foreach($item['price'] as $selected)?>` but is returning me the whole Array. I could use `[0]` to target the first one but that eliminates the function of having a `select` element.

Comment: `$item['price'][$foobar]`, with `$foobar` being a variable containing the value of your chosen option.

Comment: I have the impression that you need to invest a bit more time to understand the difference between your server side logic (php) and what happens on the client side (inside a browser). The "select" switch is only evaluated on the client side, the server does not know anything about that. So you cannot implement your dynmic change in php, you'd have to make a full reload for that for every change of the switch which certainly is _not_ what you want. Instead you need to use logic on the client side, so inside the browser, which mens javascript, not php.

Comment: Ok that means i have to get the data from Json, loop through it and get the value. Ok thanks and tbh i am still not quite sure about many things while coding this.